# Changing A UILabel In Swift After Load Change

Tags: swift, label, uilabel

I am new to `swift` programming and trying to work through the basics before moving onto more complicated programming.  Trying to solidify the fundamentals.

I am simply trying to create a "Hello" program in swift.  The basics are that a label is loaded that starts as "Hi!".  There is a `textField` and a button that says "Hello".  The idea is that the user enters his or her name in the text field and presses the "Hello" button.  The label will change to say Hello Entered Name.  Right now the code simply has a hard coded string to do proof of concept with the addition of actually passing the name to come.  The code thus far is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet var Text_Name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Label_Hi: UILabel!


@IBAction func btn_Hello() {

    var field_string: String;

   if Text_Name.text == ""
    {
        print("In it");
        field_string = "";
        self.Label_Hi.text = field_string;

    }
    else
    {
        print("In It 2");
        field_string = "Test"; //String(Text_Name.text);
        self.Label_Hi.text = field_string; //+ field_string;
    }
}



}
```

Right now if the text field (name) is left null, nothing happens (AKA the Hi! remains unchanged).  If a name is entered, there are what appears to be three dots placed under the Hi! label on the screen.  Also, the print is not showing anywhere.   Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, it seems that you probably did not connect your `@IBAction func btn_Hello()`. When connecting your button to your ViewController, ensure `Connection` is changed to Action, and `Event` is `Touch Up Inside`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.  Unfortunately, this was already completed.   I have been working with this issue since the original post and have learned to use the console and variable watch.   The console is printing out the appropriate print() text at the appropriate time.  Also, when watching the Label_Hi variable, I get optional("text") where the text is what it is supposed to be for that part of the program.  Again, when I type in a name, I get what appears to be three dots "under/behind" the label "Hi!" and if I put nothing in the text field the label "Hi!" simple remains unchanged.